# Firebase Microsoft Sign in on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, firebase-authentication

I successfully integrated Microsoft sign in using Firebase Authentication, but it seems some methods only works on iOS and not macOS. provider.getCredentialWith simply does not exist when switching target to macOS. Anyone has any idea on the possible solution or approach to this problem.

```
#if os(iOS)
provider.getCredentialWith(nil)
{
    credentials, error in
                
    if let credentials = credentials
    {
                    
        continuation.resume(returning: credentials)
    }
    else if let error = error
    {
        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    
    }
}
#else

//What to do here?
            
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the functionality is not available in the `firebase ios sdk` as indicated by this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7127) which is still open.